# Execute a method after a certain amount of time using ExecutorService

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            String call() throws Exception {

                stream.filter(fq)

                return null
            }
        })

        try {

            future.get(4, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

        }
```

Once the 4 minutes are over I want to execute another method. Where would I put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the `TimeoutException` and put your code in the catch block.

```
try {
    future.get(4, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
} catch(TimeoutException e) {
    //call your method code here, it will be called only if the operation times out
    myMethod();
}
```